# Doctrine : only one row is returned

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am getting crazy with that. The request is easy

Symfony 2.7

Position : my object Repository

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('hascotctp')
        ->from('ACCUEILBundle:' .$className, 'hascotctp');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('hascotctp.numcot', ':numcot'))
       ->setParameter('numcot', $cotisation->getNumcot());
    $qb->orderBy('hascotctp.dateff');
    
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Normally there are 2 records in the table but, unfortunatly there is only one inside $result array : the first one.

second record wanted !

I go inside Symfony debug bar to check database requests and I found it :

```
 SELECT t0_.NUMCTP AS NUMCTP_0, t0_.FINDATEFF AS FINDATEFF_1, t0_.NUMCOT AS NUMCOT_2,
   t0_.DATEFF AS DATEFF_3 
 FROM ttrhascotctp t0_ 
 WHERE t0_.NUMCOT = 199 
 ORDER BY t0_.DATEFF ASC
```

this request returns 2 records.

So what is going on with Doctrine ? (or with me ?)

I replace getResult with infamous getArrayResult(). Now I have the 2 records but of course not as a collectgion of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the second record has problems when trying to create an object from it. Is it possible to get it directly? For example, if you add an additional condition:

```php
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('hascotctp.id', ':secondId'))
   ->setParameter('secondId', SECOND_ID_HERE);

# Does it contain only the second entry?
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Another possible reason is caching or fetching records from a previously loaded list. Although it's unlikely.

Does this strange behavior occur specifically for these two records, or for any other criteria too?

You can learn about some specific of getResult() behavior by looking at the Doctrine HYDRATE_OBJECT mode documentation.